# I can not update my database. (Array2D) (JAVAGUI)

Tags: java, mysql, arrays

```
for (String[] array : checkstore1) {
    for (String element : array) {
        String sql5  = "UPDATE product SET "
        + "pro_store = '" + element + "'" + ","
        + "WHERE pro_id = '" + array + "'";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql5);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to correct my code would be helpful, thanks!

Comment: Are you getting an Exception? If so, then post the stack trace. Or is the update just not performed? We need more information.

Comment: Well it doesn't help that you haven't told us what goes wrong with it right now. You should *definitely* stop building SQL like that though, and use a `PreparedStatement` instead, with parameterized SQL...

Comment: Take a look at [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) and [Using Statement Objects for Batch Updates](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html#batch_updates)

Comment: `"WHERE pro_id = '" + array + "'"` ... ?  Where the `pro_id` equals `String[]`?

Comment: Change `+ ","` to `+ " "` ;).

Comment: Could you show an example of the SQL you're trying to generate, or better yet, explain (even without code) what you're trying to acheive?

Answer (score 0):

```
"WHERE pro_id = '" + array + "'";
```

You should check if you really want to use a `array` here.You sql will be like 
`WHERE pro_id = '[Ljava.lang.String;@72ffb'`

I think you  should change array to a String value.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: You can add a System.out.println(sql5) in your loop. And excute it in a database tool.